# How do I pull the cursor to a position using jquery?

Tags: jquery, cursor, move, pull

I am trying to make a cursor that moves around but when you stop moving the mouse it pulls toward a point on the page, how can I do this using javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move the cursor with JavaScript.

It would be incredibly annoying anyways.

Comment: ok, do you know how I can have an image following the cursor but over time it gets closer to the point on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Was previously discussed.

[jQuery Set Mouse Position (not cursor position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208729/jquery-set-mouse-position-not-cursor-position)