# Is there any way to Set the mouse position in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Set Mouse Position (not cursor position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208729/jquery-set-mouse-position-not-cursor-position)

I want to set mouse position in the event of 'onload' in javascript.Is there any way?

Comment: Just you imagine the countless ways that such feature could be abused. Hopefully it will never be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, changing the mouse cursor position is not possible in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

One can only set the z-index of the mouse cursor in Internet Explorer and Firefox on Windows:
http://laurens.vd.oever.nl/weblog/ontheedge/cursorhide/test.html ;-)

Comment: +1 A bit offtopic but very nice!

Comment: Nearly works in Safari too, but the covering div seems offset.