# jquery set mouse position inside a <div> graphic area

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, mouse-coordinates

using http://www.flotcharts.org/ to realize a complex scatterplot graphic with zoom/pan functionalities, i would like to set mouse position at specific coordinates (by example: when doing a zoom in, I would like that cursor would positioned at the center of canvass).

It ssem this function doesn't work:

```
  function setMousePosition(pos) {

  var x = pos.x;
  var y = pos.y;

  var pointX = ( Math.floor(plot.offset().left + plot.p2c(pos).left) );
  var pointY = ( Math.floor(plot.offset().top + plot.p2c(pos).top) );

 $("#placeholder").mouseXPos( pointX ).`mouseYPos`( pointY );
```

About `mouseXPos` and `mouseYPos`, firebug say:
TypeError: placeholder.mouseXPos is not a function

So my question is: there is a way in javascript or jquery to set mouse coordinates inside a graphic area ?

Comment: I dont think this is possible at all.

Comment: It is not possible through jquery. Check this SO post for all details [jQuery Set Mouse Position (not cursor position)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208729/jquery-set-mouse-position-not-cursor-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any mechanism to place a cusror to specific position **programmatically** in `Javascript`

Comment: I find a workoround... instead of move mouse (I understandis impossible), I visualize dynamically (creating on-the fly a <div>) a sort of mouse pointer marker (a simple CSS flashing rectangle)

Comment: I can't agree that this is a missing feature, I don't want to be in a position where I might be forced to click a particular button to regain control of my mouse. I hadn't considered it before, but I think that the lack of programmatic control of a user's mouse is a feature, *not* a bug.

Answer (score 4):

The mouse position ***cannot*** be set/changed via JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Totally. We have enough of user privacy invasion even without this.