# how to detatch mouseenter when clicked?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to remove the cursor from the current element clicked. I've tried the following:

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
   $(this).off('mouseenter'); 
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P3DqY/)

But this doesn't displace the cursor. Any idea?

Comment: not gettting you by mean of detach mouseenter

Comment: cursor should not be on the element

Comment: What you are currently doing is detaching the `mouseenter` event handler from the object. This will not effect the cursor in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, then you should use the CSS property of `cursor:none;`.

jQuery Example : <kbd>[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/DAA9Z/)</kbd>

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor' : 'none'});
});
```

Comment: no it still the cursor in the same position but I want my cursor anywhere outside the element

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to move the cursor somewhere else? You want to hide it for the entire page?

Comment: Move the cursor somewhere else.

Comment: It's not possible to move the cursor via Javascript. See the following question as to why it isn't possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208729/jquery-set-mouse-position-not-cursor-position

Comment: better you move the document using scrollTop()

Comment: I've a gallery and when the button is clicked the appended image is not showing but showing after I move the cursor.