# How to move the mouse pointer to the top of the page when page is loading with javascript

Tags: javascript

Just wandering, will it be possible to move the mouse pointer to the top of the page when page is loading with javascrip?

Comment: Is [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API) what you need?

Comment: This will be a bad user experience. I mean, no user wants their mouse to be hijacked on visiting a site.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post. Seems currently there is no mechnism to realize this.
[jQuery Set Mouse Position (not cursor position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208729/jquery-set-mouse-position-not-cursor-position)